# "what do I have to do ..." or "what should I do ..."

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, british-english

Are both of the following sentences correct?

Which one of the following sentences would the native British English speakers likely to use in daily conversation?

> - I have lost my driving license. what **do I have to do to** get new one?
> - I have lost my driving license. what **should I do to** get new one?

Is there better way to say that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have lost my driving license. What do I have to do to get new one?

It is fine, but note correction of added capital.

> I have lost my driving license. What should I do to get new one?

It is fine, but note correction of added capital.  Here in NAm, we'd use **driver's** license insteading of **driving**. I don't know what is common in the UK.  ON Edit -- or sometimes **permit**. Driver's permit.